# PhotoScore and AudioScore is grayed out.

Tags: software, transcription, sibelius

I've installed trial version of Sibelius software for OS X in order to transcribe some audio tracks.

However when I'm on *Import* tab (in *Quick Start*), *PhotoScore* and *AudioScore* are disabled, so I can't click on them.

Any reason why? Or how do I activate or use it?

[image: Launch: PhotoScore, AudioScore]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're disabled, because they refer to separate programs which weren't installed: [PhotoScore](http://www.neuratron.com/photoscore.htm) & [AudioScore](http://www.neuratron.com/audioscore.htm).

Install these programs, so they can be recognised and launched by Sibelius in order to edit the imported data.

Comment: There are separate downloads for the demo versions of photoscore and audioscore that are bundled with Sibelius. See http://www.sibelius.com/download/index.html.